# missing microsoft docker images

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

I am fairly new to docker and running some tutorials at the moment.

I have craeted a docker file through VSCode Extension and I have the following :-

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CatalogDotNet5.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "CatalogDotNet5.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "CatalogDotNet5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CatalogDotNet5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CatalogDotNet5.dll"]
```

Now I run `docker build -t catalogdotnet5:v1 .` in the console, and after everything finishes, I check the docker images and I only have :-

```
catalogdotnet5   v1        7ecc6bc42bba   27 seconds ago   217MB
```

Shouldn't I also have `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0` and `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` as docker images?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the base images available on your docker host, then don't rely on the build tooling to create them as a side effect, explicitly pull them with `docker pull`. Depending on the build tooling, you may not see intermediate and base images.

As an example, with buildkit, it builds images directly in containerd, in a different namespace that docker doesn't see, and then exports the result back to docker. So you won't see the components in the build cache mixed in with the docker image cache.

Comment: Ok good to know!  Its because the tutorial I was following had them listed as a seperate image and mine did not work.  I will pull them separately and see if that works.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JMon really no need to pull. If you try running them directly, instead of your built image, docker would pull it automatically. The tutorial is probably using an older version of Docker without buildkit enabled.

Comment: so just building the dockerfile should be enough right? docker build -t catalogdotnet5:v1 .

Comment: @JMon enough for what? What error are you trying to solve? I don't consider a listing that looks different from a tutorial to be an error.